# Component Exception Error: Objects are not valid as React child (founs: object with keys {_U,_V,_W,_X}) If you meant to render a collection of childre

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, fetch-api

> Component Exception Error: Objects are not valid as React child (founs: object with keys {_U,_V,_W,_X}) If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

  const getVideos = async () => {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${store.getState().jwt}`
      },
    })
    let json = await response.json();
    // this.setState({ message: json});
    setVideos(json);
    alert(json[0].title.toString());

  } catch (error) {
     alert(error);
  }
};

getVideos();
```

Comment: i think the problem is in your render() , share it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to outside `useState` from `getVideos()` 
you can't use hooks inside regular function it must be one of:

- React function component.
- custom React Hook function.

see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) for more details.

try this will solve your error

```js
//put useState outside getVideos function
const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);


const getVideos = async () => {
  
};
```